# Error when I :require goog.lang.Sha256 in Clojurescript?

Tags: clojure, closures, google-closure-compiler, google-closure, clojurescript

When I try to require Sha256 in a clojurescript project:

```
(ns tutorial-client.sha256
  (:require
   [goog.crypt.Sha256 :as hasher]))
```

I get no actual compilation errors, but I do get the following when I open the clojurescript->js output in a browser.

```
Uncaught Error: Undefined nameToPath for goog.crypt.Sha256 base.js:586
Uncaught ReferenceError: cljs is not defined rendering.js:7
goog.require could not find: goog.crypt.Sha256 base.js:333
Uncaught Error: goog.require could not find: goog.crypt.Sha256 base.js:337
Uncaught ReferenceError: cljs is not defined behavior.js:8
Uncaught ReferenceError: cljs is not defined app.js:100
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'IE' of undefined eventtype.js:60
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'entryPointRegistry' of undefined events.js:1084
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'IE' of undefined browserfeature.js:35
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Error' of undefined asserts.js:71
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined base.js:1407
Uncaught Error: Invalid event type events.js:139
Uncaught Error: Invalid event type events.js:139
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined
```

I think most of it can probably be ignored, the issue is the top error that it basically can't find goog.crypt.Sha256 . The funny thing is I can make all errors go away if I change the code to the following.

```
(ns tutorial-client.sha256
  (:require
   [goog.net.XhrIo :as hasher]))
```

Anyway, I just want to have access to goog.crypt.sha256 . Thank you.

Comment: It should be enough to have the js loaded in the browser when your clojurescript is invoked. If you do advanced compilation, don't forget to set the externs.

Comment: Ah, I see you are doing it in pedestal. Funny, I did a crypto app as first project, too. Yes, in pedestal the goog.require is not necessary. Make sure you have the js in application.html and (if you need it in the dataflow aspect) tooling.html.

Comment: Thanks I gave it a go but I seem to be having troubles, probably really simple but that is how these config things seem to go. I posted a git example of my problem on the pedestal-users group. I will write an answer if I get one.

Comment: If ayone wants to take a swing at fixing the pedestal code directly, it is linked here. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pedestal-users/9iy6YsIWDEo

Comment: I should have added, you can run the above code by cd'ing into the directory, typing "lein repl" and then start the server by typing "(start)". Then visit the app at port 3000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that when accessing raw javascript functions you need to make use of Clojure's interoperability features, just like you would on the JVM. This means your namespace declaration changes to this:

```
(ns tutorial-client.sha256
  (:import goog.crypt.Sha256]))

(.log js/console (Sha256.))
;; this will log the instance to the browser console
```

From here on you should be able to use it normally, by calling the instance's javascript functions:

```
(def sha-256 (Sha256.))
(.update sha-256 [])

(.log js/console (.digest sha-256))
```

Comment: I tried following the above directions, but it still does not seem to work (same errors). I posted a link to a git version of the problem in the question comments.

Comment: I didn't pay enough attention and didn't realise you're using pedestal . I have no experience with it so I'm not sure I'd be able to help. The above works with a vanilla Clojurescript app.

Comment: Shoots, well, I appreciate your help.

Comment: This is probably because Pedestal has an old ClojureScript dependency, not sure if they allow or recommend overriding.

Answer (score 1):

Shucks, well, it turns out I am soft in the head. I was looking that the completely wrong thing and the real problem was that goog.crypt.Sha256 was a recent library, and it was not included in the version of clojurescript I was using.

From the google message group:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pedestal-users/9iy6YsIWDEo

Comment: Glad you figured it out :)